# Mongodump doesn't work as expected

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I am trying to host my database online and based on what I have found online, I need to use `mongodump` to export my database first.

The way to use `mongodump` if am not wrong is:

```
mongodump -d <db-name> -o <directory>
```

when I use the above command, I get the following error in the terminal:

```
Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
```

I tried to add `--host=127.0.0.1` after `mongodump` as follows:

```
mongodump --host=127.0.0.1 -d <db-name> -o <directory>
```

But I still get the same result. What am I doing wrong here?

**Update:**

I managed to overcome the error by starting the MongoDB service with the following command:

```
brew services start mongodb
```

Now when I run `mongodump`, it seems to be working but I can't find it when I navigate to the directory where it supposed to be located!

**NOTE:** I am using Meteor technology, and I am accessing my database with `meteor mongo` command

Comment: Are you able to connect to mongo shell by running just `mongo`?

Comment: @andresk no i can't, it shows me "connect failed", I usually run my mongo using "meteor mongo" because am using Meteor JS to build my project

Comment: @andresk I managed to get mongo running, but not mongodump, i will update my question,

Comment: and whats the error you are getting now?

Comment: @andresk, please do check the question again, I edited it again :) sorry

Comment: Does the mongodump outputs anything? Is the output directory empty?

Comment: Is this really "I couldn't connect to my DB because I hadn't started it"??

Comment: @andresk the output is empty and the command seem to work fine!

Comment: @andresk I remember my lecturer told me, if you see no output in the terminal, it means the command has been executed successfully, is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

Run `mongodump --db <database> --port 3001` from the directory you want the output files to be created (it will create a dump dir with the files)

The port is 3001, as it seems meteor doesn't use Mongodb default port

Also, if nothing appears, try running with the `-v` flag for [verbose mode](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--verbose), this will help you to find out why your files are not being created. Also, be sure yout database name is correct.

Comment: it didn't work, however I believe the problem isn't with your solution because I get the following error message in the console: "positional arguments not allowed: [meteor]", I believe the reason is because my database name is "meteor" which is a command i use to run my project. therefore, I believe the problem might be because of the database name.

Comment: I am working on changing it now, I will update you once am done :). Thanks

Comment: You could try using `--db`, or simply use `mongodump` to dump all data from your mongo instance. Also remember to never use `=` sign. For example, it's not `--host=127.0.0.1`, but `--host 127.0.0.1`

Comment: okay, thanks a lot for the help, will accept the answer if it solved it for me :)

Comment: i got "dumping up to 0 collections in parallel" when i used "-v" with "mongodump -v --db meteor". its actually not dumping any data! -_-

Comment: Then this db probably doesn't exist in this mongo instance. I've done a little research, as I don't know meteor and it seems it runs on port 3001. So try `mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor`

Comment: (If it doesnt connect try running `meteor run`  before)

Comment: (ALSO the port should be displayed when you run `meteor mongo`)

Comment: Great! I'll update my answer with the correct port then. Glad it worked

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing mongodump from a remote server it can happen that versions are incompatible. This results in no documents being dump without any warnings. (At least from my tests, mongodump 2.6.10 won't be able to dump from mongod 3.2.13)

Also, make sure bash special characters are not breaking up your query.

Example:

```
mongodump --db DB_name --collection colname --query "{$or: [something1, something]}"
```

The previous query won't work as you need to escape the `$` with `\`.

```
mongodump --db DB_name --collection colname --query "{\$or: [something1, something]}"
```